# Ruby '.find' method only returning first occurrence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have models as follows: User has_many goals, Goal has_many tasks, Task has_many day_tasks. I'm trying to write a method which finds all day_tasks that

1. belong to a certain user
2. have `:target_date == Date.today` (target_date is a column in the day_tasks table).

I want to put the results into the @day_tasks array.

my code:

```
@user = current_user
@day_tasks = DayTask.find { |x| x.task.goal.user == @user && x.target_date == Date.today }
```

This code only returns the first record that matches these criteria. I've also tried using the  DayTasks.where method with the same code in the braces, but I just a "Wrong number of arguments ( 0 for 1 )" error. Could someone explain why my method only returns the first occurrence and what exactly the difference is between .find and .where?

Comment: I don't do rails but the regular ruby `find` is supposed to return the first element found while `find_all` returns all of them, may be worth trying if `find_all` works on your case.

Comment: @derp I tried using find_all but got an undefined method error. Ran DayTask.respond_to? :find_all and sure enough it returned false...

Comment: @derp: `find_all` is deprecated in Rails 3, replaced by `find(:all)`. A better solution is to use `where`, as shown in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, haven't picked up Rails yet but thought it may be worth a try.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You wrote this:

```
@day_tasks = DayTask.find { |x| x.task.goal.user == @user && x.target_date == Date.today }
```

The `find` method here is actually falling back to `Enumerable`'s `find`, which is an alias for `detect`, which takes a block and will return the first element in that collection that matches the block's conditions *or* will return `nil`.

In order to fix this, you're going to need to use ARel's query stuff that's built-in to ActiveRecord.

```
DayTask.joins(:task => { :goals => :user }).where("users.id = ? AND day_tasks.target_date = ?", @user.id, Date.today)
```

The `joins` method here will join the tables that match the *association* names in your `DayTask` model and related models. This means you must have a `task` association on the `DayTask` model and on that model have a `goals` association and on the goals model  have one for `user`.

The `where` will then construct an SQL condition that will query the joins to find all records that belong to a user and have a `target_date` of today.

Comment: Very informative, thanks for that explanation! Although right now I'm just trying to get this method to work, I'll look into the correct way to do it later.

Comment: @Grant: This way is the way to get it to work *and* the correct way.

Comment: As a small improvement, that where clause should work simply as _where(:target_date => Date.today, :goals => {:user => current_user})_. No need to drop into SQL, I think.

Answer (score 1):

please check the ActiveRecord Query Interface for Rails 3.x :

http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

you'll probably want find(:all, ...)  or where()

Comment: Thanks for the links, they'll come in real handy in the future!

Comment: sorry.. that was a typo on my part... :-P

Comment: Please add the relevant information into your answer.